# SQL Efficiency - 3 nested Selects as a column lags terribly

Tags: sql, database

I have a query that works but takes forever. My "LastName" column is 3 select queries. I know there must be a better way to do this.

```
SELECT LOANS.BALANCE, TAXES.TAX_DUE,
       (SELECT SBAOFFCR.LAST_NAME 
        FROM SBAOFFCR 
        WHERE SBAOFFCR.INITIALS = 
              (SELECT PMGTMAIN.OFFICER 
               FROM PMGTMAIN 
               WHERE PMGTMAIN.BOC_NUM_STRING = LOANS.BOC_NUM_STRING 
               AND PMGTMAIN.SEQ =
                   (SELECT MAX(SEQ) 
                    FROM PMGTMAIN 
                    WHERE PMGTMAIN.BOC_NUM_STRING 
                                             = LOANS.BOC_NUM_STRING))) AS LastName

FROM LOANS 
LEFT JOIN TAXES 
ON LOANS.BOC_NUM_STRING = TAXES.BOC_NUM_STRING
WHERE LOANS.BALANCE > 0
```

`PMGTMAIN` has several/many records for each one record in `LOANS` AND `TAXES`.
`PMGTMAIN` has employee intials in column `OFFICER` which can be referenced in the `SBAOFFCR` table as column `INITIALS` and in the `SBAOFFCR` table there's a column `LAST_NAME` which is what I need for each record from the `LOANS/TAXES` join.
And I can't take just any `OFFICER` from `PMGTMAIN WHERE LOANS.BOC_NUM_STRING = PMGTMAIN.BOC_NUM_STRING`, it has to be the one with `MAX(PMGTMAIN.SEQ)`. Like I said, my query works, but it took like 10 minutes.

Comment: Clearly your LOANS are overextended and the OFFICERS are starting to be affected.

Comment: I can't comment on your SQL, though I agree there is probably a way to simplify.  However, you can reduce time by applying indexes to your linking fields if they are not already in place.

Comment: Tag your question with the DBMS you are using, and provide us with the execution plan of your SQL statement. Also, the DDL would be appreciated, or even better: a representative [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: In the worst case execution scenario, a subquery in the select clause of a sql statement gets executed once for every row of data. Try using joins/subqueries in the from clause instead as suggested by @X-Zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid we'd generally need a bit more information why it's taking so long, although I do feel creating indicies (if they don't already exist) is probably your best bet.

Give this a try though, just in case:

```
SELECT Loans.balance, COALESCE(Taxes.tax_due, 0), SbaOffcr.last_name
FROM Loans
LEFT JOIN Taxes
ON Taxes.boc_num_string = Loans.boc_num_string
JOIN Pmgtmain as Main
ON Main.boc_num_string = Loans.boc_num_string
LEFT JOIN Pmgtmain as Exclude
ON Exclude.boc_num_string = Loans.boc_num_string
AND Main.seq < Exclude.seq
JOIN SbaOffcr
ON SbaOffcr.initials = Pmgtmain.Officer
WHERE Loans.balance > 0
AND Exclude.boc_num_string IS NULL
```

Oh - why are your tables/columns given *short* names?  It seems mostly like it would be confusing.  And something is hinting to me that your schema could potentially be tweaked.

Comment: +1 for rewriting as using joins. Although I'm too lazy to verify logic.

Comment: I'll try that out Monday, thanks! The table names are short because it's superbase (20 year old database). The table schemas are tweaked but the creator was new to DBA. I've migrated it to access (I would have preferred SQL server but that's not in the cards unfortunately)

Comment: I got "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" :/

Comment: I hope the error message gives you more help than that.  Nothing is jumping out at me as obviously wrong, at least from a DB2 point of view.  If there's something that's Access specific (like some way table names have to be presented), I'm afraid you're on your own - I don't have any familarity with that system.  And are you sure you can't use one of the stripped down versions of SQL Server - isn't there a CE version or something that's free/cheap?